# Redirect after authentication in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I would like to redirect users back to the page they were viewing before the login page after successful login in Laravel 5. Currently if the user writes a wrong username/password he is redirected to the login page again, with error displayed, and I would like to keep it that way. Also I want this to work when user clicks on login button on a page and also in the situation when user is redirected to login page automatically.

Seems to me that

```
protected $redirectTo = "/";
```

is the key thing here, but I don't know how to get it to "redirect to last page which isn't the login page". Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = URL::previous() != url('login') ? URL::previous() : null;
$previousUrl = old('previousUrl', $url);
```

Pass `$previousUrl` to your login view.

In your login view put `previousUrl` field: `<input type="hidden" name="previousUrl" value="{{$previousUrl}}"/>`

In your `AuthController.php` update constructor like that:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->redirectTo = app('request')->input('previousUrl') ? : $this->redirectTo;
    <...>
}
```

Not tested, but it should work.

Comment: wait so I should have:
`$url = URL::previous() != url('login') ? URL::previous() : null;  
$previousUrl = old('previousUrl', $url);`  
in every view that I want this to be possible on?

Comment: No, put that code in `AuthController`, where view is returned and attach `$previousUrl` to that view.

Comment: I feel stupid but, which function is that exactly? Here is what my AuthController looks like http://pokit.org/get/img/692be56a2778fa74ab98a9b51646bbdd.jpg

Comment: Create `getLogin` method override. Original method sits in `AuthenticatesUsers` trait. Thats how Your method should look like http://pastebin.com/KNd1vsCi

Comment: How do I override the getLogin method? I tried editing it in the vendor folder, but I'm aware that we should't do that, but it still didn't work.

Comment: nono, do not change vendor directory content. Just put this method in `AuthController` and You are good to go.

Comment: It worked! Didn't know that the one in AuthenticatesUsers get overriden if I write the same method here. Thanks a bunch! But still doesn't work if I miss my password.

Comment: What is your exact Laravel version? Run `php artisan --version` to check.

Comment: 5.0. I think I need to go and forward the previousUrl to the method that autenticates the user, if he is misses the password, we go back to the getLogin page and forward the previousUrl value again.

Comment: Yeah works perfectly now that I forwarded previousUrl in the postLogin back to the view.

Answer (score 0):

use URL::previous() in your redirect or `return redirect()->back();` once you know the login was succesful.

Also, you can save the url in the session and use it later at any time.

Comment: I guess `return redirect()->back()` will try to redirect to a login page.

Comment: if login has failed previously, yes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Laravel 5.2

You must store the previous URL when the user enters your login page:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url

Session is an option: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-session

After that you should fill $redirectTo with that information when user tries to login: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#included-authenticating

I wrote an example using a Middleware.

First you need to create one:

```
php artisan make:middleware BeforeLoginForm
```

Now we need to override the default route for Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm, so we can add our middleware to that route:

app/Http/routes.php

```
Route::auth();

$this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm')
    ->middleware('before.loginform');
```

Define an alias for our Middleware:

app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'before.loginform' => \App\Http\Middleware\BeforeLoginForm::class,
];
```

Our middleware will store the previous URL using the session helper:

app/Http/Middleware/BeforeLoginForm.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class BeforeLoginForm
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        session()->put('before_login_url', url()->previous());
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The constructor of our AuthController will change the redirectTo property with our previously stored URL:

app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $redirectTo = session()->get('before_login_url');
        if (!empty($redirectTo)) {
            $this->redirectTo = $redirectTo;
        }
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
```

#### For Laravel 5.0 (only what is different)

You should register your route like this:

app/Http/routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::controllers([
        'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
        'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

Route::get('auth/login', [
    'middleware' => 'before.loginform',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin'
]);
```

Then modify redirectTo on your AuthController:

app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php

```
public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->registrar = $registrar;

    $redirectTo = session()->get('before_login_url');
    if (!empty($redirectTo)) {
        $this->redirectTo = $redirectTo;
    }

    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}
```

I could not test that, will do it later.

> Pay attention because the value of the property "redirectTo" will influence not only the authentication but also the registration process.

Comment: Where exactly is the controller that comes before the login view, and where is the one that processes what is done after the input (I assume this one is the AuthController)?

Comment: Sorry, I had not seen your question before I updated the answer. You can use a Middleware to process anything before an action.

Comment: This method seems good, but I'm using Laravel 5.0, so my files look differently. This is my AuthController http://pokit.org/get/?c9877ac27dd8134ee5787c0bfc8e98d9.jpg, and this is my routes file: http://pokit.org/get/?124ec6ff4349413eb32f7d57cea1ab60.jpg. I tried your method by bluntly copypasting and it did't work. I also tried to be a bit smarter but still couldn't get it to work and I think its because of these 2 files and I'm unsure what to do.

Comment: I edit the answer for Laravel 5.0 but I could not test it yet.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but still doesn't work and with all the work you put into this i really want to give you a star. I have no function showLoginForm in my AuthController, also I'm kind of confused with your usage of 'before.loginform' when the middleware is called BeforeLoginForm, typo maybe? At the current state I think that the middleware gets skipped entirely.

Comment: Oh yeah and I should add that the route 'login' is wrong in my case, since the login is at 'auth/login', but that's not that important I guess

Comment: Sorry, you have no showLoginForm. Your AuthController has a getLogin method through the AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers trait. The middleware is called BeforeLoginForm and you will create an alias for it in app/Http/Kernel.php file through the $routeMiddleware property. Yes, the route is auth/login. I will update my answer to reflect those changes.

Comment: Yeah I went messing around in the AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers trait, even tried editing the getLogin method, even though I'm aware that we shouldn't do that, but it did not work. Is there a safer way to edit what happens in the getLogin method without editing it in the vendor folder?

Comment: You don't need to change the getLogin method since you are using a middleware for that. But if you really want you need to create a Controller class who extends the AuthController and overrides the getLogin method. And you will need to apply the auth routes to your new controller class.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel allows you to override the `redirectPath()` method in the `AuthController` which normally will use the `redirectTo` property, but you can set it to something dynamic.

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    return request('redirect');
}
```

And in the login blade template place a hidden `input`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ url()->previous() }}">
```

Comment: I still have a problem if the user misses his password once, then the data of previous url isn't saved anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
redirect()->intended();
```